# Using a native HTML element attribute dynamically in Angular - Can't bind to 'form' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to set up a form in an Angular template, as per the example given in
["HTML Input form* Attributes" - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes_form.asp):

```html
<form action="/action_page.php" id="form1">
...
</form>

...
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" form="form1">
```

The important bits are the `form="form1"` on the last line and the `id="form1"` on the first line, which link the `<input>` element to the `<form>` element, without having to have the `<input>` nested within the `<form>`.

When I try to update my Angular HTML template with a hardcoded value, everything works fine:

```html
<input form="my-form-id">
```

But I need to update it dynamically:

```html
<input [form]="dynamicVariable">
```

Unfortunately, using the `[form]` attribute with square brackets causes the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'form' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)
```

Is there a way to use the `form` attribute dynamically in an Angular template?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<input [form]="dynamicVariable">
```

Use

```
<input [attr.form]="dynamicVariable">
```

Although I don't think this works for practical Angular usage. For example, if I try:

```html
  <td>
    <form [id]="tagMappingForm.value.tagName" [formGroup]="tagMappingForm">      
      <input formControlName="childrenTags">
    </form>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input [attr.form]="tagMappingForm.value.tagName" formControlName="label">
  </td>
```

The first input works fine, but the second input causes an error:

```
NG01050: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
```

Comment: You should absolutely use the "normal" way of defining a form in Angular unless you have a good reason to do otherwise :) You could alternatively write a directive that takes `form` as an input and automatically does a `input.setAttribute('form', this.form)`.

Comment: Thanks @Cuzy . It's necessary in my case in order to avoid wrapping any table elements in a <form> element - because doing so causes the widths of the td elements to stop aligning. I've found another workaround (basically not using the <form> with `[formGroup]` attribute). It means I'm not getting the benefit of the `formGroup` directive and not being able to use things like `formControlName`. It's unfortunate but better than having misaligned table columns!

Answer (score -1):

Here , **AfterViewInit** **lifecycle hook** is used to set the form property of the input element to the form element using plain JavaScript.
Create your form group as usual in your component class:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const formElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#my-form');
    const inputElement = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#lname');

    inputElement.form = formElement;
  }
}
```

Your template will have the form and input element separately:

```
<form id="my-form">
  <!-- ... other form controls ... -->
</form>

<input type="text" id="lname">
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the problem I had in the original post. When you use [form] in Angular you get the error: `Can't bind to 'form' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)`

Comment: I have updated the code, try this